# Why is this called the orthogonal projection of $u$ on $W$ if $proj_Wu$ is not orthogonal to $u$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Why is this called the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf u$ on $W$ if $proj_W \mathbf u$ is not orthogonal to $\mathbf u$?

---

[image]

Comment: Think of $u$ falling over $W$ only by the action of gravity. So the fall is orthogonal to $W$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it called “Orthogonal Projection”? Why not just “Projection”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/112212) from the sidebar. The answers there would be helpful for answering this question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the text, $u = w_1 + w_2$ where $w_1 \in W$ and $w_2$ is orthogonal to $W$.

It is called an "orthogonal" projection because the difference $w_2 = u-w_1$ between $u$ and its projection is itself orthogonal to $W$.

(That it deserves to be called a projection is because $\mathrm{proj}_W(u) \in W$, and $\mathrm{proj}_W(\mathrm{proj}_W(u)) = \mathrm{proj}_W(u)$.)

Comment: I am not fully comprehending.  It says "orthogonal projection of **u** on $W$, but **u** is not orthogonal to $W$.

Comment: $w_1$ is called an orthogonal projection of $u$ because $w_1$ differs from $u$ by a vector $w_2 = u-w_1$ that is orthogonal to $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because  $(\operatorname{proj}_W \mathbf u - \mathbf u)$ **is** orthogonal to **W**, i.e. its projection on $W$ is a zero-length vector ("orthogonal" to it). So if you make an analogy with 3D space, to make this projection you drop a perpendicular on the "plane" $W$.